# Setting up Oracle Connection Pool with Jetty

Tags: oracle, jetty, connection-pooling

How can I go about setting up an Oracle 10g connection pool in Jetty. I had a look at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/DataSource+Examples, and Oracle 10g is listed under Non-pooling Data Sources, does that mean i cannot have an oracle connection pool or is there a different way?

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble with this as well.  I could not get the OracleConnectionPoolDataSource to work with pools as I saw some examples use.  I used the more general OracleDataSource and it worked.

```
<New id="terminalfour" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg/>
        <Arg>jdbc/SiteManagerDB</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
                <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:oci:@server</Set>
                <Set name="User">user</Set>
                <Set name="Password">*****</Set>
                <Set name="ConnectionCachingEnabled">true</Set>
                <Set name="ConnectionCacheProperties">
                    <New class="java.util.Properties">
                        <Call name="setProperty">
                            <Arg type="java.lang.String">InactivityTimeout</Arg>
                            <Arg type="java.lang.String">300</Arg>
                        </Call>
                        <Call name="setProperty">
                            <Arg type="java.lang.String">AbandonedConnectionTimeout</Arg>
                            <Arg type="java.lang.String">600</Arg>
                        </Call>
                        <Call name="setProperty">
                            <Arg type="java.lang.String">TimeToLiveTimeout</Arg>
                            <Arg type="java.lang.String">600</Arg>
                        </Call>
                        <Call name="setProperty">
                            <Arg type="java.lang.String">InitialLimit</Arg>
                            <Arg type="java.lang.String">10</Arg>
                        </Call>
                        <Call name="setProperty">
                            <Arg type="java.lang.String">MaxStatementsLimit</Arg>
                            <Arg type="java.lang.String">50</Arg>
                        </Call>
                        <Call name="setProperty">
                            <Arg type="java.lang.String">MinLimit</Arg>
                            <Arg type="java.lang.String">20</Arg>
                        </Call>
                    </New>
                </Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
```